# Scala compiler errors when applying an optional transformation function to an optional value

Tags: scala

I have a list of values in Scala of various types - strings, ints, doubles mostly. Some of these values may be null. We can think of this as a `List[Option[AnyRef]]`. For each value in this list, if it exists, I want to generate a string containing the value between parens; if it does not exist, then just an empty string. In addition, before the value is inserted between parens, it may need to have a transformation applied to it. For instance, if the value is an `Option[String]`, I may want to apply the `trim` function.

I've approached this by thinking of the data structure as a map of an optional value paired with an optional function operating on that value and returning a string (I don't know how to specify that in Scala, as I think Map[Option[A], Option[(A) => String]] is not correct, as it implies that every option key is of the same type). Here's what I have written so far with example data and functions:

```
lazy val messageContext = Map(
  None -> None,
  Some("hello") -> None,
  Some(4) -> Some(negate _),
  None -> None
) map { t => wrapText(t._1, t._2)  } toList

private def wrapText[A](option: Option[A], transFn: Option[(A) => String]): String = option match {
  case Some(o) => " (%s)".format(transFn.getOrElse(stringIdentity _)(o))
  case _ => ""
}

private def stringIdentity[A](a: A) = a.toString

private def negate(n: Number) = n * -1
```

I'm getting a compiler error, though:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[java.lang.Number => java.lang.String]
 required: Option[AnyVal{def getClass(): java.lang.Class[_ >: Double with Int <: AnyVal]} => String]
  ) map { t => wrapText(t._1, t._2)  } toList
```

Is my approach close on this? Is this easily possible with Scala, or would I have to resort to some scalaz magic to make this really work?

Thanks.

EDIT: Correct output for the above input would be this:
`List[""," (hello)"," (-4)",""]`

Comment: Step back for a minute - why all these values of different types? What are they representing? `List[AnyRef]` is almost never what you want, but it's hard to say if you want an `HList`, or some custom algebraic data type, without knowing where these values come from. Also, you almost certainly don't want to use a `Map` - how do you distinguish between the first `None` key and the second?

Comment: You're right about the `Map` not being an appropriate data structure...the immediate change would be a `List[Tuple2[...]]`. As for the different types: they are representing meta-data that may or may not exist on some explanatory text. For instance, I have a string saying something like, "This product was released recently". I then may or may not have a java.util.Date specifying the release date - if I do, I'd like to print "This product was released recently (November 2012)", which would require first formatting the Date object. If I don't have the date, I'll just stick with the original text

Comment: How does your `negate` function compile? `java.lang.Number` does not have `*` operator. Do you have some implicit conversions for this? Also, does `negate` return `String` as it should?

Answer (score 2):

No magic needed. I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but to restate

- `None` in the input means    `""` in the output
- `Some(v)` in the input means `" (%s)".format(trans(v))` in the output, where `trans` is some optional transformation of the value

Ex:

```
val input = List(None, Some("hello"), Some(4), None)

def trans(v: Any) = v match {
   case num @ 4 => -num
   case _       => v  // identity
}

val output = input.map {
   case Some(v) => " (%s)".format(trans(v))
   case _       => ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that a `Map[A,B]` has two type parameters for the whole map, and not a couple of type parameters for each `tuple`. What you have in mind to do cannot be done using a `Map`, because the `Map` will take as type parameters the most common ancestors of keys and values:

```
scala>  import StackOverflowTest

StackOverflowTest.messageContext
import StackOverflowTest

scala> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Option[java.lang.Comparable[_ >: java.lang.Integer with java.lang.String <: java.lang.Comparable[_ >: java.lang.Integer with java.lang.String <: java.lang.Comparable[_ >: java.lang.Integer with java.lang.String <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable],Option[java.lang.Integer => Int]] = Map(None -> None, Some(hello) -> None, Some(4) -> Some(<function1>))

scala>
```

When you put tuples of different types in a map or in a sequence, you lose the type information about each tuple, and you keep only the first common parent. If you need a data structure which is able to keep a Map of tuples where each `Tuple2[A,B]` has different `A,B` you need a more dynamic structure, such as Shapeless records or HList.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

The second problem here is that the semantic of Number * 1 is not defined in Java,you need to use the subtype of number required, for example java.lang.Integer.

The third problem is that your wrapText require a `transFn: Option[(A) => String])` while your negate output value type is not String (and actually there is no * defined for the java class Number). Taking away the `Map` part and correcting the negate method, if you try to compile just the following:

```
  private def wrapText[A](option: Option[A], transFn: Option[(A) => String]): String = option match {
    case Some(o) => " (%s)".format(transFn.getOrElse(stringIdentity _)(o))
    case _ => ""
  }

  private def stringIdentity[A](a: A) = a.toString

  private def negate(n: java.lang.Integer) = n * -1

  wrapText(Some(4),negate _ )
```

This won't compile with error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Option[java.lang.Integer => Int]
required: Option[? => String]
wrapText(Some(4),Some(negate _) )
```

If you finally correct the negate to return a String, you will hit the final wall

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Option[java.lang.Integer => java.lang.String]
required: Option[Int => String]
wrapText(Some(4),Option(negate _) )
```

The problem here is that while Scala and Java perform automatic boxing and unboxing, they do not perform automatic conversion for type parameters: Option[Int=> String] is not of the same class as Option[java.lang.Integer=>String],so you have to force the type of the first option to get it correctly compiled:

```
  wrapText(Some(4:java.lang.Integer),Some(negate _) )
```